# How show image not in public

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

i have this structure:

```
my_app
  application
    controllers
    forms
    models
    views
  data
    signature
  library
  public
  tests
```

I want to show in my view the images are in `data/signature`

How can I do since the helper `$this->baseurl()` points to public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a showImageAction(), set headers and put the image through using file_get_contents() or similar.

Comment: so there is no way to use the HTML img tag?

Comment: only if your data dir is in the public path (which I don't think is a good thing to do)... Else you need to point your image tag to a controller-action putting it through. For security reasons I would suggest you only have your public directory in the public and put sensible data outside of it and put it through using a controller action which can check authorization.

Comment: precisely because they are sensitive data I put them outside the document root!
But how should this action that shows the image in the view?

Comment: Just like `<img src="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'image', 'action' => 'show', 'param' => 'SIGXXX')); ?>" alt="" />` where SIGXXX ist your signature image identifier used for the controller and param the name of the parameter used.

Answer (score -1):

If you have images inside DOCUMENT_ROOT you can show them by pointing browser to location: `http://example.com/images/image.jpg`, but if they aren't in DOCUMENT_ROOT you can use script (example.com/img.php?id=100) or some subdomain (img.example.com/100.jpg maby) to show images not in DOCUMENT_ROOT of example.com.

//EDIT

If you use nginx you could do like that: http://www.leftjoin.net/2011/03/efficient-file-serving-in-php-application-with-nginx/

Comment: in zend framework the document root is public, but my image are in the: `data/signature`

Comment: In server config DOCUMENT_ROOT is always public and if you have files aoutside DOCUMENT_ROOT you should write script or new action in controller to serve those files. Or use some subdomain